Python code copy/paste in VSCode is adding an indent on every line
I am new to programing in general and trying to follow along this basic python course :https://youtu.be/8124kv-632k?si=TchTBZyVEOt9L2p5
When I copy this code:
def http_error(status):
    match status:
        case 400:
            return "Bad request"
        case 404:
            return "Not found"
        case 418:
            return "I'm a teapot"
        case _:
            return "Something's wrong with the internet"

And paste this into the python interpreter in the terminal, it gets formatted like so:
def http_error(status):
...              match status:
...                                 case 400:
...                                                         return "Bad request"
...                                                                 case 404:
...                                                                                         return "Not found"
...                                                                                                 case 418:
...                                                                                                                         return "I'm a teapot"
...                                                                                                                                 case \_:
...                                                                                                                                                         return "Something's wrong with the internet"

The exact format is in the image below as this text box is not the same width.
Python interpreter formats weird 
Here are the things I tried:

Adding the Paste and Indent extension
Shift + Insert
Copying into Notepad and then pasting
Installing the Black Formatter extension
A number of setting in settings > Editor - like Editor: Format on paste
Downgrading to 3.12


This question is similar to: Copying and pasting code directly into the Python interpreter. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
